# How could I get a root level access/permission in runtime golang application?

Tags: linux, go

Below command will creates a user but it ask sudo password.

```
cmd := "sudo /usr/sbin/useradd "+ 
      "-m -d "+home_dir+                       
      " -s "+preferredShell +
      " -g "+usrLoginName+
      " "+ usrLoginName
```

> cmdStatus,err := exec.Command("bash","-c",cmd).Output()

How to execute above command without sudo or How to provide root level permission to my golang application? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Run your golang application with sudo.

Comment: but I don't want to do this, it requires sudo password. May you please suggest some better alternatives ?

Comment: Above line is self executing (on 90 seconds interval), so how we can provide sudo password at terminal ?

Comment: Okaay, this kind of sounds like you need to learn Unix system administration. The easiest way to be root is to not give it up, so run as a system service.

Comment: @PiyushSinha Or if you are in a desktop environment you might use Polkit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit

Comment: Using `visudo` (or, to be more precise, `/etc/sudoers` file) you can specify users that will not be asked for password when running `sudo`: http://askubuntu.com/a/147265/2639

Comment: Be aware, using `sudo` without password makes security flaw. I would run this program as a system service, as @ZanLynx suggested.

Comment: @Zan I am new in Linux & Golang, so PLZ give me some suggestion about how to create System Service.